# Proof of uniqueness of the maximum element of every nonempty bounded set.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb N$ be a nonempty bounded set. So there are some $b_1, b_2 \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $s \in S, s \leq b_1$  and  $s \leq b_2$. Suppose that $b_1 \neq b_2$. Then by the definition of $S$, we have $\mathit max(S) = b_1$ and $\mathit max(S) = b_2$. This implies that $b_1 \leq b_2$ and $b_2 \leq b_1$. So $b_1 = b_2$. We conclude that every nonempty bounded set has a unique element.

How is the above proof I have written? I am quite new to proof-based maths so I am trying to consult the community on how to improve my mathematical rigor and proof techniques. Any feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: A couple of points: First (and most importantly), you introduced $b_1, b_2$ as upper bounds of $S$, then somehow concluded that they are (both) maximums. Not every upper bound is a maximum. How do you know a maximum exists (hint: you'll need the fact that $\Bbb{N}$ is well-ordered and $S$ is non-empty)? As it stands, your proof shows that $S$ has **at most** one maximum element. Second, you don't use your assumption $b_1 \neq b_2$, so it can be discarded. Your conclusion that $b_1 = b_2$ is what you wanted to show.

Comment: @TheoBendit I am introduced in my number theory class that every nonempty bounded set has a maximum element, and we proved the existence of a maximum element beforehand. The official definition of a bounded set in my class is as follows: "A set X ⊆ N is bounded if there is some b ∈ N such that for all x ∈ X, we have x ≤ b."

Comment: The uniqueness of the maximum element follows as in the linked dupe. Please delete the question once all is clear since we already have too many copies of this argument.